# Delete all nodes of a user using flags and rules

Tags: 7, rules, flags, advertising

I want to delete all nodes for a user whoes any one node has been flagged as spam.

**For example:**

If user has created 3 nodes of same/different content types, then If admin flag any one content as **spam**, then all the 3 nodes should get deleted and the user should get blocked.

I am able to block the user and delete the flagged node but not the other 2 nodes. I want to delete all nodes associated to that user.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Could you clarify how you are currently deleting and blocking the users? This can make the answer more specific to your use case.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot. Blocking and unpublishing the content.

Comment: get the user ID, and delete its content programatically

Comment: @Drupalist well that I can, but I want that to happen when user flags the node. With your solution I have to create a separate link/button.

Comment: Using rules module, set the Event on node flag and the action on the nodes delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did in this way without writing a single line of code.

1) **Add action**: Fetch entity by property: Choose *Entity type* as '**Node**', *Property* as '**Author**' and *Data selector* as '**flagged-node:author**'. Choose variable label ('**spam nodes**' in my case) and variable name ('**spam_nodes**' in my case) as you wish.

2) **Add Loop**: Select *Data selector* as '**spam-nodes**' (this will show as per your  variable label in step 1). Set variable label('**spam node**' in my case) and variable name('**spam_item**' in my case) as you wish.

3) Now click on '**Add action**' link under '**Operations**' column against the *loop* you have added in step 2. Select '**Delete Entity**' and set the *Data selector* as '**spam-item**' (this will show as per your variable label in step 2).

[image]